# SSH to server, what is address?

Tags: ssh

I am new to servers/ssh-ing, and I am having trouble understanding the basics of this. I have downloaded MobaXterm, and I have the IP address of the server(?) I want to visit, but I don't understand how to use that address to get there. The command always looks like `something@IP.address`, how do I figure out what the `something` part should be?

If this is relevant, I am trying to get to a remote Jenkins server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 'something' is normally the account name of the user you wish to connect to/as.

For example, I connect to my home server with `michael@192.168.20.140`.

You may also simply specify the IP address of the host you wish to connect to, once connected, you may be required to supply a username and password.

See here for further information about ssh:

https://www.ssh.com/ssh/command/